# Can I use wget to download all files recursively, but not their actual content?

Tags: wget, download

Sometimes, I wish to only get the directory structure of a website, but the files themselves are not important. I only want their name. Sort of like a mirror where every entry is just an empty dummy file.

Of course, doing a `wget -r` and afterwards run a script to empty all the files works fine, but it feels wasteful because it is not nice to neither the server nor my bandwidth. A more efficient, but even less elegant way is to manually stop and restart the process every time you hit a large file, or set a very short time-out. At least that significantly reduces the amount of data I have to download.

My question is: Can I make wget only create a file, but not download its content? Or am I using the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: See the `--spider` option.  For example: `wget -r -nv --spider http://example.com`, then parse the output.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Not exactly what I want, the --spider option actually downloads the files, but deletes them afterwards. That does not save any bandwidth.

Comment: You can't know what `example.html` links to without downloading it first.  There is no such thing as a "`ls -R` over HTTP", spidering is your best option.  And I believe you do save some bandwidth with `--spider`, f.i. I don't think image files and the like are downloaded.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Oh... Yeah, thinking of it, following links without downloading them is a bit hard... you are right, my test was a bit flawed, and images or other content is ignored. Want to write up an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting an answer as requested:

Use the `--spider` option:

```
wget -r -nv --spider http://example.com
```

Then you can parse the structure of the site from the output.  This won't download files that stand no chance to contain links, such as images.